# GetProcAddress em processos externos

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de saber se há alguma alternativa a `GetProcAddress` para se utilizar em processos externos?

Algo como:

```
GetProcAddress(handle,GetModuleHandle('user32.dll'),PChar('MessageBox'));
```

Alguém sabe?

Comment: Porque você precisaria de algo diferente? Qual o seu objetivo? Sem dar mais informações sobre o porque de você querer algo além do `GetProcAddress` para encontrar um símbolo em um executável qualquer não há como dar uma resposta.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Agradeço pela resposta. Bom na verdade eu não exatamente preciso de algo diferente, preciso pegar a Address e o ModuleHandle de um processo externo, entende? com o GetProcAddress eu só consigo pegar os dados de mim mesmo, e oque eu quero é pegar de outro processo, o notepad por exemplo.

Comment: Você teria que injetar uma dll no processo externo e utilizar GetProcAddres na sua dll carregada no processo externo. Veja esse [artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces)

Comment: Então @EProgrammerNotFound essa é a questão de eu querer usar em processo externo, eu não quero injetar ela no processo. Por que? porque preciso fazer isso em todos processos, e injetar dll não me cairia bem nesse caso. Agradeço novamente pela resposta.

Comment: A outra alternativa seria injetar o código via thread remota. Esse artigo também descreve essa opção